# How can a div element be set dynamically (in runtime)

Tags: angular

How can I let a div element appear and disappear? For example if a condition like a specific height of the previous div has reached, it should let appear a new div (2) element. It also should to disappear if the height of the div element has reached the minimum height and if I hit the backspace.

```
<div id="invoice" class="create" fxLayout="row">
<div class="invoice-container">
    <div class="card">
        <textarea class="description">
    </textarea>
    </div>
    //This div should be shown in the DOM dynamically
    <div class="card" style="margin-top: 10px;">
        <textarea class="description">
      </textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: Preview]

I have put an example on stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-173u1h

Comment: Do you mean that if the user types longer data in the first textarea, it should move to 2nd text area?

Comment: I mean to create another div "card". The textarea fields are only for test purpose, because I can change the height of the div card

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with using Viewchild and give keyup function to first textarea as a way [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zldjsb)

```
<textarea (keyup)="change($this)" #el1 [(ngModel)]="text1" class="description" > </textarea>
```

then just check with height

```
  change(){
    var firsttext=this.text1.split(" ");
    var lastword=firsttext[firsttext.length-1];
    var height=this.el1.first.nativeElement.scrollHeight;
    var clientHeight=this.el1.first.nativeElement.clientHeight
    if(height>clientHeight){ 
         this.text1=this.text1.substr(0,this.text1.length-lastword.length);
         this.text2=lastword;
      this.el2.first.nativeElement.focus();
    }   
  }
```

Comment: Thx but I meant the div card as whole. The textarea fields were just for my own test purpose.
Like on a word processor where a text doesnt fit anymore and create a "second" page

Comment: Updated answer demo check it

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with `*ngif` just put this directive into the div you want to show and hide.

```
<div *ngif="your condition"> Your Content <\div>
```

Next time please don't add your code with a picture. Thats easier to read.